# Localization with jQueryUI datepickers setDate method

Tags: jquery-ui, localization, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using norwegian locale for the jQueryUI datepicker plugin. This works sweet as a pie, but when using the setDate method, it seems to not care about the localization:

```
var now = new Date();
$('#date').datepicker('setDate', now);
```

This returns `24 May, 2012` when it actually should return `24 mai, 2012`.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.datepick-no.js"></script>
```

Don't forget you can set your defaults:
For example:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults(
  $.extend(
    {'dateFormat':'dd-mm-yy'},
    $.datepicker.regional['no']
  )
);
```

There are particular issues with Norwegian outlined here:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7437

As an aside Keith Wood's Page on jQuery-Ui datepicker is brilliant.
http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

A sample specifying everything on the datepicker:

(example for GBenglish)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $.datepicker.regional['en-GB'] = {
            closeText: 'Done',
            prevText: 'Prev',
            nextText: 'Next',
            currentText: 'Today',
            monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                    'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
            weekHeader: 'Wk',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ''
        };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);
    });
</script>
```

Make sure this is placed in the `<head>`.

Comment: That didn't work for me. Hmmm. I might add that the `#date` element is a text input field.

Comment: Can you please check if you are loading the Norwegian localisation  last and not updating the global defaults after that?